# Opencart: Removing/Editing The Navigation Bar

Tags: opencart

I'm trying to remove some unwanted features on the navigation bar, and edit some of the keywords, such as 'customer' to 'staff'/'users'. Which file path do I go to edit to do so?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBjK8.png)

Comment: Please write the proper questions. what do you actually need? and upload with proper screenshot as well

Answer (score 0):

To change the categories, please log in to the Opencart admin then go to Catalog >> Categories where you will see lists of categories. You can edit the existing top-level categories or add the new categories. Then in the data tab, you will see a Top checkbox field where you can check to show in the main menu.

or

go to your catalog/theme folder -->common --> header.tpl, there is your link to change

Answer (score 0):

You can change Text through Language file.

```
admin/language/en-gb/common/column_left.php
```

In this file code will will something like bellow

```
$_['text_customer']          = 'Customers';
```

*There is no need to remove left menu you can manage through admin panel
Create new User Groups*

```
System -> Users -> User Groups
```